# PHP validation for Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a new problem. My whole website is written in PHP as well as all validations. Is there a way to do validations in php and then execute javascript like the example bellow?

```
if (@$_POST['submit']) {
    if ($txt == "") {
        $err = "No comment";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            function myFunction() {
                var txt' = '$txt';
                var dataString = 'txt=' + txt;
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'ajaxjs.php',
                  data: dataString,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(php) {
                      alert(php);
                  }
               });
            }
        </script>";
    }
}

<div id="text">
    <form action="" method='POST'>
        <textarea maxlength="2000"></textarea>
        <input type='button' onclick="myFunction()" name='submit' value='post' />
    </form>
</div>
```

This doesn't work. So I'm wondering how should I do it?
I guess forms don't work with javascript, but how do I do it without a form?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as output? You don't use anywhere your javascript function.`myFunction`

Comment: @PeterDarmis Sorry, I posted the wrong core. Updated now. It doesn't work with `onclick="myFunction()"` either

Comment: @Menel if you're trying to execute a function `onsubmit` then you might use `<form onsubmit="formSubmit();">` and make `formSubmit()` return false, this is important.

Comment: @Menel you don't need to use php here only jQuery/Javascript is enough

Comment: @timmyRS that sounds like something that could solve this for me. How do I make formSubmit() return false? Do I do it at the end of validation in the javascript or?

Comment: @timmyRS Yes, figured it out. Thanks man, that solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use php at all. You can post your textarea data like in the below example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="text">
<textarea id="txtArea" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
<button id="btnSubmit" name='submit'>post</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$("#btnSubmit").on('click',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var txtValue = $("#txtArea").val();
   if(txtValue.length==0) {
     alert("You have not entered any comments");
   } else {
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxjs.php',
        data: {txt:txtValue},
        cache: false
        })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Your code has a couple of errors.

- You are asking if `$txt == ""` whilst `$txt` was not *visibly* set.
- Your text area has no name
- Your `if` doesn't ask if `empty($_POST["submit"])`

Second of all: You mentioned that you want the code to be executed on submit of the form. Therefore you can simple do this:

```
<form onsubmit="formSubmit();">
    ...
</form>
<script>
function formSubmit()
{
    if(...)
    {
        return true; // Valid inputs, submit.
    }
    return false; // Invalid inputs, don't submit.
}
</script>
```

The `return false` is **important** because if it would miss, the form would be submitted as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is:
 1. add function for submit event.
 2. call ajax with form fields values as data. 
 3. do vildation inside php called with ajax request and return status code (valid/not valid)
 4. analyse code in js and output error/success message.